# Not able to play video using GvrVideoTexture in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, exoplayer

Video player not ready to Play!

I am trying to develop Video Demo Scene from the GVR SDK Unity but While building the demo scenes for Android everytime I'm getting this error:

```
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
GvrVideoPlayerTexture:Play() 
(at Assets/GoogleVR/Scripts/Video/GvrVideoPlayerTexture.cs:484)
GVRSample.AutoPlayVideo:Update() 
(at Assets/GoogleVR/Demos/Scripts/VideoDemo/AutoPlayVideo.cs:62)
```